# What is the right .gitconfig syntax for http.sslCAInfo certificate for specific server?

Tags: git, https, certificate, self-signed, git-config

I'm using a remote git repository via https, which has a self-signed certificate. To make git aware of the self-signed certificates, I have the following in my .gitconfig:

```
[http]
sslCAInfo = /home/user/myselfsigned.cert
```

This works fine, but when I add another remote with a CA signed certificate, git (or curl?) wrongly tries to use the cert file for this remote, too. What is the correct syntax to apply the certificate to a specific remote?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807313/adding-self-signed-ssl-certificate-without-disabling-authority-signed-ones/23807432#23807432) has answer to your question as well:

```
git config http."https://code.example.com/".sslCAInfo <downloaded certificate>.pem
```

And gitconfig file will be smth like:

```
[http "https://code.example.com/"]
    sslCAinfo = /path/to/<downloaded certificate>
```

Although it doesn't work for me yet...

Comment: It seems to work. I have git 1.9.1 (Debian wheezy backports), maybe you have a pre 1.8.5 version?