# github: server certificate verification failed

Tags: git, github, debian

I just created a github account and a repository therein, but when trying to create a local working copy using the recommende url via

```
git clone https://github.com/<user>/<project>.git
```

I get an error like

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/<user>/<project>.git': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /home/<user>/.ssl/trusted.pem CRLfile: none

I'm on Debian Jessie, and I would have expected both Debian and GitHub to provide / rely on a selection of commonly accepted CAs, but apparently my system doesn't trust GibHub's certificate.

Any simple way to fix this (without the frequently recommended "GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true" hack and similar work-arounds)?

EDIT:

Additional information:

- The ca-certificate package is installed.
- Installing cacert.org's certificates as
  suggested by @VonC didn't change anything.
- My personal ~/.ssl/trusted.pem file does contain a couple of entries, but to be
  honest, I don't remember where the added certificates came from...
- When removing ~/.ssl/trusted.pem, the git error message changes to

  ```
   fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/tcrass/scans2jpg.git/': Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
  ```

Comment: What's in mentioned CAfile? Maybe your SSL isn't finding the ca-certificates? Did you install them?

Comment: I have edited the answer to make sure git references those ca.

Comment: In my case, the problem was simply incorrect date.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

2016: Make sure first that you have certificates installed on your Debian in `/etc/ssl/certs`.

If not, reinstall them:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
```

Since that [package does not include *root* certificates](https://www.brightbox.com/blog/2014/03/04/add-cacert-ubuntu-debian/), add:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/cacert.org
sudo wget -P /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/cacert.org http://www.cacert.org/certs/root.crt http://www.cacert.org/certs/class3.crt
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

Make sure your git does reference those CA:

```
git config --global http.sslCAinfo /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

---

[Jason C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/616460/jason-c) mentions another potential cause ([in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35821245/github-server-certificate-verification-failed/35824116#comment72366364_35824116)):

> It was the clock. The NTP server was down, the system clock wasn't set properly, I didn't notice or think to check initially, and the incorrect time was causing verification to fail.

[Certificates are time-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21181447/6309).

[dopamane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4051020/dopamane) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35821245/github-server-certificate-verification-failed/35824116#comment137731126_35824116):

> This was the issue for me on WSL.
> Ran [`sudo hwclock -s`](https://askubuntu.com/a/229279), and I could successfully clone the submodule.

---

2022: [Auspex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/334719/auspex) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35821245/github-server-certificate-verification-failed/35824116?noredirect=1#comment129795717_35824116):

> ca-certificates does indeed contain root certificates.
> It doesn't contain the CAcert root certificates.
>
> This might have been a good answer 6 1/2 years ago, but those certificates were suspect way back then and haven't improved.
> There's a reason they're not in the `ca-certificates` package.
>
> These days we have [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/), so everyone has certificates with reliable auditing and nobody needs to rely on CAcert.

Comment: I also get the same messages. Specifically mine says fatal: unable to access 'url/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none. I am using git over ssh. Would that make a difference?

Comment: @CodedContainer Yes it does: the CAs (Certificate Authorities) validate a public keys for TLS certificates (using in https). ssCAinfo has no bearing for ssh url. Are you sure your remote url does *not* start with https?

Comment: Hm. I just suddenly started getting this error today, only on one device (a Raspberry Pi) that hasn't been touched since the last time it worked. I ran through all the steps in this answer, and it grabbed some new certificates, but I'm still getting the same error (the git URL does start with https, and it's on gitlab.com). Any other ideas?

Comment: @JasonC Is the Git version the same on those Raspberry Pi boxes?

Comment: @VonC I figured it out. It was the clock. The NTP server was down, the system clock wasn't set properly, I didn't notice or think to check initially, and the incorrect time was causing verification to fail. It was [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22945443/616460), after a load of other failed attempts.

Comment: @JasonC Thank you. I have included your comment and link in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: the time was the reason in my case, nothing related with actual certificates.

Comment: `ca-certificates` does indeed contain root certificates. It doesn't contain the CAcert root certificates. This might have been a good answer 6 1/2 years ago, but those certificates were suspect way back then and haven't improved. There's a reason they're not in the `ca-certificates` package. These days we have LetsEncrypt, so everyone has certificates with reliable auditing and nobody needs to rely on CAcert

Comment: @Auspex Good point, thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @JasonC Thanks! This was the issue for me on WSL. Ran `sudo hwclock -s` and could successfully clone the submodule.

Comment: @dopamane Thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 144):

You can also disable SSL verification, (if the project does not require a high level of security other than login/password) by typing :

`git config --global http.sslverify false`

enjoy git :)

Comment: It is not an obligation, only a (very strong) recommendation. SSL certificates are about end-to-end encryption between you and a *known* end-point. Desactivating ssl certificate exposes you to a MiM attack (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)

Comment: The problem with that kind of short answer (and many others I have seen for the past 8+ years) is the complete lack of context or recommendation: One could quickly copy-paste it without understanding the consequences.

Comment: Even the CIA, in its latest WikiLeaks dump (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vault_7) tries to avoid sslVerify false: look for section "The "Workaround Self-signed Certificates" Trick" in https://wikileaks.org/ciav7p1/cms/page_1179773.html

Comment: This is true, but in another context where the same user is working with several machines (home machine, office machine ... any computer) on the same project playing with the certificate becomes binding on everything if the main objective is not to avoid an intrusion because the system is developing ...and we want to focus on that 
(git accept only one certificat /projet  you must evry time when you change machine to generate certificate and update the setting of the project!! )

Comment: You can specify indeed a certif per project since Git 1.8.5: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23807432/6309

Answer (score 53):

I also was having this error when trying to clone a repository from Github on a Windows Subsystem from Linux console:

> fatal: unable to access 'http://github.com/docker/getting-started.git/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

The solution from @VonC on this thread didn't work for me.

The solution from this [Fabian Lee's article](https://fabianlee.org/2019/01/28/git-client-error-server-certificate-verification-failed) solved it for me:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -servername github.com -connect github.com:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null | sed -n -e '/BEGIN\ CERTIFICATE/,/END\ CERTIFICATE/ p'  > github-com.pem
cat github-com.pem | sudo tee -a /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Comment: Same! VonC's answer doesn't work me, probably because I'm in WSL too. This answer solved the problem.

Comment: I struggled for two days and this finally resolved the issue for me :)

Comment: This works for me, on a self-hosted gitlab instance where I changed all `github.com` to my domain, but won't it stop working when the LetsEncrypt certificate expires in two months (maybe sooner, when I replace the cert in a month)?

Comment: In hindsight, I think I'm wrong in the comment above. When you add the certificates this way it's adding all of the leaf, root, and intermediate certificates individually, and while the leaf will expire in a couple of months, the root certificate is what was needed. Though even that has an expiry. But the root certificate for _this_ site expires in 2035.

Answer (score 34):

It can be also self-signed certificate, etc. Turning off SSL verification globally is unsafe. You can install the certificate so it will be visible for the system, but the certificate should be perfectly correct.

Or you can clone with one time configuration parameter, so the command will be:

```
git clone -c http.sslverify=false https://myserver/<user>/<project>.git;
```

GIT will remember the false value, you can check it in the `<project>/.git/config` file.

Comment: Git remember this setting only for the project or for global context?

Comment: Only for the project.

Answer (score 26):

I had a similar problem and got the error message:

```
fatal: unable to access XXXX server certificate verification failed. CAfile: none CRLfile: none
```

It suddenly happened when I had tried to connect to my regular (WORKING!) gitlab server, SSL created with letsencrypt, from git under WSL2 ubuntu.

There were no problems accessing the server from the browser, the SSL chain seemed OK when checking with tools like https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html

you need to update your CA certificates.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
sudo update-ca-certificates


# now it should work perfectly
git pull
```

it might happend because of this:
https://techcrunch.com/2021/09/21/lets-encrypt-root-expiry/

Comment: Below modification helped me resolve issue on AWS Codepipeline 

`sudo apt update -y
sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh -v`

Comment: All I seemed to need was `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates` thanks! (ubuntu 18.04 wsl)

Comment: this works if you have updates or extended support - but if you are outside of that window, there are no updates.

Answer (score 7):

Another possible cause is that the clock of your machine is not synced (e.g. on Raspberry Pi). Check the current date/time using:

```
$ date
```

If the date and/or time is incorrect, try to update using:

```
$ sudo ntpdate -u time.nist.gov
```

Or, on a virtual machine (e.g. Ubuntu VirtualBox):

```
$ timedatectl set-ntp no
$ timedatectl set-time YYYY-MM-DD
$ timedatectl set-time HH:MM:SS
$ timedatectl set-ntp yes
```

Comment: Related: [WSL2 Clock is out of sync with Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65086856/wsl2-clock-is-out-of-sync-with-windows)

Answer (score 4):

In Linux terminal, run following command:

```
export GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=1
```

It works for me. So Simple!!

> **Note:** This has **major** security implications.

Answer (score 1):

To me a simple

```
sudo apt-get update
```

solved the issue. It was a clock issue and with this command it resets to the current date/time and everything worked

Comment: `apt-get update` won't fix an incorrect clock. I suspect that what happened is that your clock was wrong enough that ntpdate (or whatever you're using to get the time) was fixing it by _slewing_ -- that is making very small changes to the clock until it's correct rather than changing in a single jump -- and that `apt update` took long enough that your clock was right when it finished.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me when getting such an error (happened with gitlab for me):

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/<user>/<project>.git': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /home/<user>/.ssl/trusted.pem CRLfile: none
```

was to get the `.pem` file from the certificate page of the website (accessible when clicking on the lock icon left of the url) and directly copy it into the folder `/etc/ssl/certs/`. From there, git was able again to interact with gitlab.

Answer (score 1):

For me, simply removing `sudo` solved.

I was trying to `sudo git clone ...`, just doing a `git clone` worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is an edge case, but I think worth mentioning.

In my case, I had an Apache server proxying for a GitLab instance. GitLab is supposed to handle LetsEncrypt certificates internally, but it's become broken on my server, and I can't figure out how to fix it. Consequently, the Apache server receives HTTPS requests and is configured with a valid certificate, and forwards the requests over HTTP to the GitLab server. Browsing the GitLab site worked perfectly, showing a valid certificate.

The GitLab server, however, by default promotes any HTTP request to HTTPS whenever  `external_url` uses the HTTPS protocol. And there was still a broken LetsEncrypt certificate on the internal NGINX server. While this seemed to make no difference at all within browsers, it made any operations using the `git` CLI fail!

Setting `nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = false` in the `gitlab.rb` configuration makes the communication from proxy to GitLab server work purely over HTTP, with the proxy handling HTTPS communication with the client.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have sudo rights, you can still add the remote server's certificate to your local Git configuration without updating the system's certificate store. Here's the process:

1. Download the server's certificate and add it to your local Git configuration as a trusted certificate. Follow these steps:

- Download the certificate from the remote server:

  `echo -n | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect gitlab_url:443 2>/dev/null | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > ssl_certificate.crt`
- Add the certificate to your Git configuration:

  `git config --local http.sslCAInfo /path/to/ssl_certificate.crt`

/!\ If the command doesn't output anything, it's possible that the server is not serving a certificate, or there might be an issue with your OpenSSL installation.

As an alternative, you can try to download the certificate using a browser:

1. Visit the URL https://your_gitlab.url in your browser.
2. Click on the padlock or "Secure" icon next to the URL in the address bar.
   View the certificate details. The exact steps to view the certificate details vary between browsers.

For example:

- In Chrome, click on "Certificate (Valid)" in the connection tab, then click on the "Details" tab.
- In Firefox, click on "More Information," then "View Certificate."
  Export the certificate as a file (usually in the X.509 Certificate format with .crt). Save the certificate to your local machine.

3. Once you have the certificate file, you can add it to your Git
   configuration:

   `git config --local http.sslCAInfo /path/to/ssl_certificate.crt`

Answer (score -2):

Try to connect to the repository with the URL:

```
http://github.com/<user>/<project>.git
```

**(`http` instead of `https`)**

In your case, you should clone like this:

```
git clone http://github.com/<user>/<project>.git
```