# Git Clone Fails: Server Certificate Verification Failed

Tags: linux, git, ssh, git-clone, ca

I've been unable to `git clone` just about any github repo because of this error

> fatal: unable to access 'github_url': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/rel3_dodroot_2048.crt CRLFile: none

I've noticed a few other people have had a similar error, but with the certificate in the `.ssl` folder. I've never seen anyone have this problem with the certificate in the .ssh though, and I have no idea how to fix it.

Environment:

- Nvidia Jetson TX1 running Ubuntu 14.04
- Specific Github of Interest (although it happens with all of them)
- https://github.com/rbgirshick/fast-rcnn.git

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution...
I guess a script (I hadn't looked at) ran on my computer which ran the line

```
git config --global http.sslVerify true
```

So the solution was simply to change run

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

Heh...

Comment: I was trying to download using git clone in an ubuntu vm which I created on my PC. This worked for me.

Comment: This answer should at least add a warning saying doing this could potentially increase your security risk.  You are disabling SSL verification, and on a global scale.  Ideally, you add that git server's certificate to your local machine so it will trust this server.  Even if you don't do that, disable SSL verify in the one repo only, not globally.

Answer (score 9):

I get same error like this and I run following command:

```
export GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=1
```

It works for me and I am using Ubuntu OS.

Comment: +1 great. And you can use it without making the change permanent like 'GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=1 git clone ...' which is better for security.

Answer (score 6):

Careful with disabling security features like certificate verification! This error indicates that there's some misconfiguration of your machine, assuming GitHub.com actually does have a valid cert. Overriding the error by disabling verification just adds more configuration issues without resolving the underlying problem.

In my case, I discovered that my system clock was wrong, and was set *before* the GitHub.com certificate was supposed to be valid. Fixing the clock resolved the issue without needing to expose my machine to security threats.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error while building a Docker image. The fix was to add the following to my Dockerfile. Be sure to put the call to `update-ca-certificates` before the `git clone` call.

```
RUN apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends ca-certificates \                             
  && update-ca-certificates \
  && git clone whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

To do your clone without dealing with cert problem this post ([disable certification verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35821245/github-server-certificate-verification-failed/41946599#41946599)) can help you.

Answer (score -2):

Delete all reference to the SSH certificate from your Github account and validate manually with an e-mail address and password.

Comment: I don't follow. In my account settings it doesn't list any ssh keys

Comment: TRy adding an SSH key in your Git account settings.