# server certificate verification failed - but only for client on same machine as server

Tags: git, ssl, lets-encrypt, gitbucket

Since approximately start of October, I get this message when running any command with remote access to a git repo (e.g. `git pull`) on the same machine as the server runs on (i.e. on mygitbucketurl host):

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://mygitbucketurl/repourl/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: none CRLfile: none
```

This is on an Ubuntu 20.04.3 machine; I am running this against my own [gitbucket](https://github.com/gitbucket/gitbucket) server which is behind an apache2 reverse proxy for https, using a letsencrypt certificate.
I am aware of the recent change in letsencrypt's ROOT CA.
However, the strangest thing is that **no client running on a host other than the server**, but connecting to the same server (same repositories actually) shows this problem (not from a windows client, not from another ubuntu machine).

My server actually does pass tests on ssllabs.com (even though I'm not 100% sure I've done everything correctly here - ssllabs shows 2 paths, and one of them ends in the "DST Root CA X3", "Valid until: Thu, 30 Sep 2021 14:01:15 UTC EXPIRED" - should this be there? or should I be concerned if it is there)?

I've seen [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69394518) and tried the proposed resolution of renewing the trust store; also the current time seems correctly set to me.

So I'm out of ideas what's going on here. Could git somehow be using a different trust store than the Ubuntu system? Why am I only seeing this message when running a client on the same machine that the server runs on, but not on different machines (seems to indicate a client-specific issue; but another machine running the same operating system does not have this problem, and updating the trust store also does not help - what can I further do to debug this?)

Added to answer questions from comments:

- mygitbucketurl is the local-network IP of the server machine (192.168....)
- `$ ldd /usr/bin/git`:

  ```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff825d8000)
    libpcre2-8.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007f2f3b9eb000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f2f3b9cf000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f2f3b9ac000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2f3b7ba000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2f3bdcd000)
  ```

As for Workarounds: The quick workaround is of course to set config http.sslVerify=false (per command), and a half-permanent workaround I have applied to one of the affected repositories was to use ssh instead of https.
I'd still be interested in the root cause of this, though.

Comment: What's the IP for `mygitbucketurl` on that host ? 127.0.0.1 ? Could it be that apache loads a different config ?

Comment: Git is built against libcurl. On Ubuntu it's probably a dynamically loaded libcurl, so `ldd` should tell you which libcurl is being loaded. Other than that, I don't know what to look for at this point.

Comment: added info in IP and `ldd git`