# How to set Git config options for all subdomains?

Tags: git, ssl, github

Similar to how you can set [Git config options for a specific URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23807432/1233435) like

`git config http."https://code.example.com/".sslVerify false`

I'd like to set them for all subdomains. How can I use wildcards? The following doesn't seem to work

`git config http."https://*.mycompany.com/".sslCAInfo <downloaded certificate>.pem`

Comment: With Git 2.13 (Q2 2017), your syntax will actually work! See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43056419/6309).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How can I use wildcards?

With Git 2.13 (Q2 2017), you will be able to use wildcards!

See [commit a272b9e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a272b9e70a48a355b6dd7ff0179c11f8da7ef0f3), [commit af99049](https://github.com/git/git/commit/af99049ca92f5a5d16d8cce9727b859ac5c9ee00), [commit 3ec6e6e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3ec6e6e8a0870a32357689e2179d845700539623), [commit 3e6a0e6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3e6a0e64a47497d1addaf063e13865c67cbeb009), [commit 3343995](https://github.com/git/git/commit/33439956b7f6f91434673d49e8c8af5c90b4a0fa) (31 Jan 2017) by [Patrick Steinhardt (`pks-t`)](https://github.com/pks-t).
Helped-by: [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a411726](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a411726930a6fc97d5a1f62d8d8d59b8587b10f2), 27 Feb 2017)</sup>

> ### `urlmatch`: allow globbing for the URL host part
>
> The `<url>` part in "`http.<url>.<variable>`" configuration variable
>   can now be spelled with '`*`' that serves as wildcard.
>
> E.g. "`http.https://*.example.com.proxy`" can be used to specify the
>   proxy used for `https://a.example.com`, `https://b.example.com`, etc., i.e. any host in the `example.com` domain.

Answer (score 1):

The analysis of the [host matching part](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/urlmatch.c#L457) in git's url matching procedure suggests that wildcards are not supported:

> ```
> /* check the host and port */
> if (url_prefix->host_len != url->host_len ||
>     strncmp(url->url + url->host_off,
>             url_prefix->url + url_prefix->host_off, url->host_len))
>         return 0; /* host names and/or ports do not match */
> ```