# OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection was reset in connection to github.com:443 while try to git push

Tags: git, github, openssl

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/XXX/XXXXX.git/': OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection was reset in connection to github.com:443
```

Suddenly I'm getting above error while I try to git pull, git push, or clone the repo.

Comment: Do you use self-signed certificates to connect to your github ? it seems for me you are tryin to access private repo, I assume for the company you are working for, Right?

Comment: Can you access the remote repository directly in the browser using the remote URL?

Comment: @MostafaHassan I'm not sure. How can I check it ?

Comment: Yes I can able to access remote repository

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23293417/what-is-the-right-gitconfig-syntax-for-http-sslcainfo-certificate-for-specific

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I also encountered a similar situation; that's when I came across an answer on Code Grepper by Shibbir Ahmed, where he provided this:

`git config --global --unset-all remote.origin.proxy`

That solved the issue for me.

Comment: how to undo this command ?

Comment: how can I find my  remote.origin.proxy?

Answer (score 24):

When I couldn't use my VPN Apps because it doesn't connect in Iran at the moment, I used GitHub desktop.

Comment: Hmm, That's true. SSL Protocol in completely closed in Iran! No SSL Connection is allowed.

Comment: I couldn't even with GitHub desktop. I unchecked the `Use system OpenSSH` in the advanced option, however, I still couldn't. Are there any solutions?

Comment: The Solution for Iran :)

Comment: **** iran and iran's Internet

Answer (score 22):

As Iranian Govenment has recently blocked OpenSSL protocol in most ISPs, we have to switch from `HTTPS` to `SSH` or use Github Desktop (This solution is just for Iranian people like me!).

I recommend installing `GitHub Desktop` if you can. I couldn't install it since I want to use `GIT` in the terminal. So, I switched from `HTTPS` mode to `SSH` mode using this command [(Reference)](https://gist.github.com/m14t/3056747):

```bash
git config --global url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
```

Then I created an SSH key and added it to ssh agent using this [tutorial on github](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent).

Also, to test your ssh key, you can use [(Reference)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection):

```bash
ssh -T git@github.com
```

Comment: Thank you my bro. I couldn't even with GitHub desktop, however, after adds ssh-key, visual studio and github desktop work like a charm.

Comment: For me github is just working while dev.azure.com is not

Answer (score 6):

Based on the
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66666084).

In the case of the Iran SSL ban, it is possible to run a proxy on the arbitrary free port on your localhost and then reconfigure the git proxy setting.
For example, I use the Psiphon to run a proxy by changing the setting shown in the image:

[image]

Run the command:

```
git config --global --add remote.origin.proxy "127.0.0.1:1089"
```

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
git config --global http.sslBackend schannel
```

Comment: thank you: just installed git, tortoisegit on a fresh windows 11 and could not clone devops azure repository with the similar error message. This change alone solved the problem

Comment: didnt work for me.

Comment: working good for me

Answer (score 5):

Try again by using a **VPN**.

If it doesn't work or you don't have access to any VPN, take your chance by using **SSH** instead of HTTPS as following steps:

1. [Generate a new ssh key](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) with a passphrase if you don't already have one.
2. [Import the ssh key to your GitHub account](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account).
3. Clone the repository using SSH.
4. Now if you're lucky, the `pull`, `push`, and other git commands should work.

[image]

Comment: my issue was VPN related.

Comment: The SSL protocol is not allowed at all !

Answer (score 4):

generally fatal errors are related to network connection, you can use VPN or proxy on you'r system.

Answer (score 4):

In the Visual Studio (2022) go to:

Tools > Options > Source Control > Git Global Settings > Cryptographic Network Provider > Secure Channel

[image]

Comment: Didnt work for me

Comment: OpenSSL worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

use this steps will fix that

first run this
`gh auth login`

then chose GitHub.com
then write y and press enter
select SSH and continue the steps

good lock

Answer (score 0):

I was getting an error in that format from many FOSS tools. I solved the problem by temporarily disabling my anti-virus, Kaspersky. (I wouldn't name it publicly but I already told it not to "scan" secure connections so there's no reasonable explanation for this problem.)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was an expired token.
Just generate a new token (if this is auth form you're using) and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

On the github.com website, go to Settings / SSH and GPG Keys -> New SSH Key. Add your public SSH key from your computer. You can find the string for this e.g. under Windows in the path C:\Users\User.ssh or under Linux in the path /home/admin/.ssh in the file `id_rsa.pub`.

Answer (score 0):

In my Case below method works:
execute below command under angular root path:

```
git config user.name "<User Name>"
git config user.email "<Authenticate Email ID>"
```

after executing above command into my VS code allow me to commit the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Run below command

```
git config --global https.sslBackend schannel
```

Answer (score 0):

UPD: I found out! This antivirus closes the connection. Try to close your antivirus.

---

I had the same problem.

Write `gh auth login`, select SSH (instead of HTTP).

Then for cloning use in Github SHH (instead HTTP) and use in command line `git clone git@github.com:...`.

Or if you use Android Studio select "Get project from Version Control" - and paste `git@github.com:...`

Answer (score 0):

- For thoes where @RahmladAramide answer did not work please try below setp.

**Restart your system** <- I know this may sound simple but this one works for me really well. I am not sure what is the reason but it has to do with something related to VPN and network proxy setting.