# git: OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection was reset in connection to github.com:443

Tags: git, github, proxy, git-bash

This is the pretty old problem, but I couldn't solve it using old answers. When I try to push github (git push origin master), I receive this error:

```
     OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection was reset in connection to github.com:443
```

I tried these solutions :

1-Trying this command:

`$ git config --global --add remote.origin.proxy ""`

2-Opening new terminal and using push command again.

3-Runing this command:

`$ git config --global http.sslBackend "openssl"`

4-Unsetting proxy:

`$ git config --global --unset http.proxy      $ git config --global --unset https.proxy`

None of these solutions are working.
Any advises could make me happy!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenSSL SSL\_connect: Connection was reset in connection to github.com:443 while try to git push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71571965/openssl-ssl-connect-connection-was-reset-in-connection-to-github-com443-while)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me: **Using SSH Key**

1. [Generate a new SSH key / Add it to the ssh-agent](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)
2. [Add the new generated SSH key to your GitHub account](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)
3. [Clone the repository using SSH](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/cloning-a-repository) **[click SSH tab!]**

   (I recommend you test it on a new folder different from your current working path)

**That's it. Now try to pull/push. Everything should be worked**
*Open the file **.git/config**
If you notice, the URL parameter value in [remote "origin"] is changed!*

Useful docs here:
[Connecting to GitHub with SSH](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh)
[Testing your SSH connection](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection)
[Working with SSH key passphrases](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases)

Comment: worked for me! special tnx

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Instead, the questions should be closed as duplicates.