# OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection was reset in connection to github.com:443

Tags: git, github

when i turn off vpn git does not work :
"fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/mojtaba013/formik-app.git/': OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection was reset in connection to github.com:443
Pushing to [https://github.com/mojtaba013/formik-app.git"](https://github.com/mojtaba013/formik-app.git%22),
please help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenSSL SSL\_connect: Connection was reset in connection to github.com:443 while try to git push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71571965/openssl-ssl-connect-connection-was-reset-in-connection-to-github-com443-while)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I followed the instructions of "Using SSH Key" but I didn't get the appropriate result.

The more easy and working way is to install "GitHub Desktop" Application .
It Works nice and properly.
https://desktop.github.com/
[GitHub Application][1]
[1]: https://desktop.github.com/