# OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection was reset in connection to github.com:443 git windows

Tags: windows, git, github, visual-studio-code

my windows (11 home) get error when (clone,push,pull and etc.)

**fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/alaabibest/fgsdfgsdgfsdfg.git/': OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection was reset in connection to github.com:443**

can anyone help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenSSL SSL\_connect: Connection was reset in connection to github.com:443 while try to git push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71571965/openssl-ssl-connect-connection-was-reset-in-connection-to-github-com443-while)

Answer (score 5):

on the global setting change cryptographic network provider to 'Secure Channel'
git config --global http.sslBackend schannel

Comment: I am using gitBatch to connect to github on Window, where should I set the above setting?